# Ant objects and references: what is the scope of a reference's ID?

Tags: ant

Seems odd that there is no documentation about it (at least no documentation that I'm aware of; and I'll be happy to stand corrected).

When I do this:

```
<fileset id="my.fs" dir="..."/>
```

What is the scope of the ID `my.fs`?

- The entire Ant execution cycle?
- The current target (and any target that `depends` on the current target)?

And, lastly, what happens if multiple threads (spawned using the `parallel` task) attempt to define filesets with the same ID?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

References are visible across the *project* in which they are defined. For example, if `<fileset id="my.fs" dir="..."/>` is placed outside any target, it will be visible for all targets in the buildfile. If it is defined in target `A`, then it will be visible in target `B` if `B` depends on `A`:

Example 1:

```
<project name="Project1" default="doIt">

   <fileset id="my.fs" dir="some_dir"/>
   ...

   <target name="doIt">
       <copy todir="some_dir_copy">
           <fileset refid="my.fs" />  <!-- this will work -->
       </copy>
   </target>
</project>
```

Example 2:

```
<project name="Project1" default="doIt">

   <target name="prepare">
       <fileset id="my.fs" dir="some_dir"/>
   </target>

   <target name="doIt" depends="prepare">
       <copy todir="some_dir_copy">
           <fileset refid="my.fs" />  <!-- this will work -->
       </copy>
   </target>
</project>
```

However, if you are invoking a *subproject*, e.g. using the `ant` or `antcall` tasks, the subproject by default will *not* inherit the references defined in the parent project (unlike Ant properties). To inherit them, you can set the `inheritrefs` attribute to true when invoking the subproject:

Example 3:

```
<project name="Project1" default="doIt">

   <target name="doIt">
       <fileset id="my.fs" dir="some_dir"/>
       <ant antfile="./build.xml" target="run" />
   </target>

   <target name="run">
       <copy todir="some_dir_copy">
           <fileset refid="my.fs" />  <!-- this will fail -->
       </copy>
   </target>
</project>
```

Example 4:

```
<project name="Project1" default="doIt">

   <target name="doIt">
       <fileset id="my.fs" dir="some_dir"/>
       <ant antfile="./build.xml" target="run" inheritrefs="true" />
   </target>

   <target name="run">
       <copy todir="some_dir_copy">
           <fileset refid="my.fs" />  <!-- this will work -->
       </copy>
   </target>
</project>
```

In case you have parallel tasks executing inside a `parallel` task, and both defined the same reference ID, then depending on the order of execution, the last one to finish will override the other task's reference.

```
<parallel>
    <fileset id="my.fs" dir="some_dir"/>
    <fileset id="my.fs" dir="another_dir"/>
</parallel>

...

<target name="doIt">
    <copy todir="some_dir_copy">
        <fileset refid="my.fs" />  <!-- this may copy either some_dir or another_dir, depending on which parallel task finished last -->
    </copy>
</target>
```